# unable to mount network share from fstab or in terminal

Tags: mount, nfs, fstab

My laptop boots normally. But earlier this week, after some updates, it is unable to mount (fstab) network shares from my QNAP.

Other computers with the same fstab connect successfully. I checked the settings on the server, but nothing seems abnormal, and, as said, other computers do connect succesfully.
I fiddled with some of the settings without succes

fstab has the following starightforward code:

> 192.168.2.73:/reviews  /mnt/reviews  nfs defaults 0 0

Here is some info about my system:
Linux 5.13.0-41-generic #46~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP  x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

I hope somebody can help out

Thanks in advance

Comment: what is the output of `mount /mnt/reviews`?

Answer (score 0):

same problem here, booting with 5.13.0-40 solves the problem